# How to translate strings in data/props object with vue i18n?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I use [Vuei18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) package. I have a lot of string in my application that defined in data object or passed as a prop into custom components and needs to be translated.

```js
data() {
  return {
     title: this.$t('main.title'),
     stuff: [
       {
         name: this.$t('main.name_1')
       },
       {
         name: this.$t('main.name_2')
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

or

```html
MyCustomComponent(:name="$t('main.custom_component_name')")
```

The problem is that if I change locale, those strings won't be translated. Those strings that defined directly in template section translates just as expected, immediately after changing locale.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to change your data structure to send these objects either as the `string` value for `i18n` or create a mapping of some sort

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ?

Answer (score 2):

Values in `data` are not reactive, try it with `computed`

```js
computed: {
  stuff() {
    return [{
        name: this.$t('main.name_1')
      },
      {
        name: this.$t('main.name_2')
      }]
  }
}
```